# What am I doing wrong with .blit() in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been attempting to learn Pygame recently but I'm having a bit of trouble. One thing is that I can't get an image to display, at all. I've tried lots of different methods but the closest I've got is getting this error message,

> ```
> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function
> ```

when trying to use `.blit()`. I've seen the command used this way in a tutorial but for some reason it doesn't work for me. My code is below.

**Python 3.8, Spyder, macOS 10.14.6**

```py
import pygame as pg
pg.init()

width = 800
height = 600

white = ((255, 255, 255))
purple = ((100, 0, 130))

screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
pg.display.set_caption("Race Game:")
clock = pg.time.Clock()

car = pg.image.load("car.png") 

def car(x, y):
    screen.blit(car, (x, y))

x = width * 0.45
y = height * 0.8

crashed = False
while not crashed:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    screen.fill(white)
    car(x, y)
    pg.display.update() 
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pygame.Surface object and the function have the same name `car`:

> ```py
> car = pg.image.load("car.png") 
>
> def car(x, y):
>    screen.blit(car, (x, y))
> ```

The function `car` covers the variable `car`, that causes the error. When you do  `screen.blit(car, (x, y))` in the function `car`, then `car` refers to the function `car` rather than the `pygame.Surface` object `car`.

You have to use different names. For instance:

```py
car_image = pg.image.load("car.png") 

def car(x, y):
    screen.blit(car_image, (x, y))
```

Comment: Thank youu so much, I should have seen that, spent 4 hours on it today.